# Java Bubble Sort String ArrayList Object

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

Can someone find why this isn't being sorted I can't seem to find what I have wrong? The output that is being displayed is how I input them after each other thus the sort method isn't working...

```
// Sorting Ticket by Alphabetic Order - Method
public void SortTicket() {
    boolean valid = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < tList.size(); i++) {
        valid = false;
        Ticket t1 = (Ticket) tList.get(i);
        Ticket t2 = (Ticket) tList.get(i++);

        if (t1.GetSurname().compareTo(t2.GetSurname()) > 0) {
            tList.remove(t1);
            tList.add(i++, t1);
            valid = true;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tList.size(); i++) {
        Ticket tmpTick = (Ticket) tList.get(i);
        System.out.println(tmpTick.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You assign the same object to `t1` and `t2`. You seem to be confusing `i++` with `i+1`.

Comment: Can you explain further to me please thanks.

Comment: If you changed `tList.get(i++)` to `tList.get(i+1)` and `tList.add(i++, t1)` to `tList.add(i+1, t1)`, you'd be closer. But then you'd have to change `i < tList.size()` to `i < tList.size()-1` so you don't run off the end of your list, and you still wouldn't have implemented bubble-sort correctly, because you're only comparing each element to one other element. Also Java method names start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three errors:
1. It does `i++` instead of `i+1`. `i++` means: return `i` then increment its value. So `t1` and `t2` are the same element.
2. It runs a full scan of the list, while it should stop at `tList.size()-1` to avoid an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
3. It isn't a real [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You need two loop.

Moreover you never use `valid`, so it should be removed. I replaced it with a flag that is true if the list is already sorted.

```
public void SortTicket()
{
    int size = tList.size();
    int end = size-1; // size-1, so you don't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException
    boolean sorted = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1 && !sorted; i++) 
    {
        sorted = true; // if you never execute a swap, the list is already sorted
        for (int j=0; j<end; j++) {
            Ticket t1 = (Ticket) tList.get(j);
            Ticket t2 = (Ticket) tList.get(j+1); // j+1, so you don't change the value of i
            if(t1.GetSurname().compareTo(t2.GetSurname()) > 0)
            { 
                sorted = false;
                tList.remove(j);
                tList.add(j+1, t1); // j+1, so you don't change the value of i
            }
        }
        end--;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        Ticket tmpTick = (Ticket) tList.get(i);
        System.out.println(tmpTick.ToString());
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you're using generics, you could declare tList as `List<Ticket> tList`. This way you don't need to cast the object returned by `list.get(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have incremented the value of `i` multiple times, which ruins the loop, here:

```
tList.add(i++, t1);
```

You should rather use `i+1`, as this doesn't effect the value of i itself.

Same is the case with

```
(Ticket)tList.get(i++);
```

I hope this solves your problem